# Cat becomes weak, a few weeks after giving premature birth

Tags: cats, breeding

I would like to know how to handle a cat that becomes very weak (her legs especially). She can't stand firm or long enough, can't run, and is very skinny--I can really feel her spine.

This started a few weeks after giving premature birth (all passed away after 1-2 days). She did not want to nurse them.

This is not even my cat. When still in pregnancy she was trying to stay in the house. Also, this is not a street cat (I think), as she has long hair.

I would appreciate some advice on this issue... thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the cat is malnourished or has some other medical problem. Can you get the cat to a vet?

Comment: you have to take the cat to a vet this might be related to the premature birth,the cat need a vet.

Comment: Hi @Mick, are there other solutions than   vet..? Sorry, I am the one posted this question. I just remembered to use the same id. Cant seem to log in with the user11155

Comment: Hi @trondhansen, are there other solutions than   vet..? Sorry, I am the one posted this question. I just remembered to use the same id. Cant seem to log in with the user11155

Comment: if a cat gets as weak as you say going to the vet is needed for the cat to possible get well.you say it is not your cat and not a street cat so it do have an owner somewere,put a collar on the cat and write a note to the owner telling them to take the cat to a vet.

Answer (score 4):

There is a real possibility that the cat was malnourished when she was pregnant (and even before). If a pregnant cat (or any mammal) cannot get enough nourishment for her fetuses to develop, then she will sacrifice her own body tissues to support their development until she has no more to give, and the fetuses either abort or are born prematurely. Also, since the mother is severely malnourished, she will not be able to produce milk and her kittens will starve.

If you cannot get her to a vet for diagnosis, then the only alternative is to provide her with as much food as you can. This will mean animal protein and fats. Vegetables and other non-meat products will not do. Neither will she be able to digest cow's milk (or other milk products), since cats are lactose-intolerant. In fact, cow's milk may make matters worse, since it will only cause diarrhoea.

If you cannot provide complete (rather than complementary) cat food (e.g. tinned cat food), and preferably as much food as she is willing to eat, then a diet of mice (or other small mammals) is a possibility (providing they have not been poisoned) if you can catch them (she will not be able to). Butcher's scraps are another possibility. I'm sorry, but I don't know what area of the world you live in, so I am trying to cover all the bases.

If an adequate diet helps her to recover, then you need to think about getting her sterilised, otherwise she will just go through all this again if she gets pregnant and you stop feeding her.

This is non-veterinary advice, but it's the best that I can give you. I am a cat owner.

If anyone else has advice to offer, please feel free to edit this answer. Alternatively, leave comments and I will incorporate them into my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Now i have not seen the cat since 2 days ago. The house-guard usually gives the cat friskies..